# GNU Make: obtain list of primary prerequisites of a rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c.o

.PHONY: all

all: foo.o

foo.o: foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h

%.o: %.c
    @printf "prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$^"
```

All the files exist except for `foo.o`, and the output is:

```
prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
```

Correctly, the automatic variable `$^` gives us all the prerequisites, including the ones obtained from dependencies stated in other rules.

Let us call the prerequisites given in the rule itself *primary prerequisites*, and the prerequisites that come from other dependencies *secondary prerequisites*.

Above, the primary prerequisites are:

```
foo.c
```

and the secondary ones are:

```
foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
```

The category is important because the primary prerequisites are the objects that the rule actually works with, which are needed to build the program. The secondary prerequisites are only involved in the correct triggering of incremental builds, not in a full build. A full build from scratch will work even if we remove the dependency line:

```
foo.o: foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
```

This is reflected in our `Makefile` structure. We usually don't write `Makefiles` with rules like these:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
    # commands
```

the additional prerequisites after `foo.c` are factored out elsewhere, often into a completely separate dependency makefile that is generated by tools, and that can be deleted completely, without affecting the ability to do a complete build from scratch.

The question is: **how can we obtain just the list of the primary prerequisites, not including the secondary prerequisites?**

This should be doable in a generic way, without any hard coding. For instance, if I have some recipe lines defined as a macro, they can be re-used in multiple rules.

```
define RULE_BODY
@printf "the primary prerequisites of target %s are %s\n" $@ [what goes here?]
endef

%.o: %.c
    $(call RULE_BODY)
```

I don't want to pass arguments to RULE_BODY for this it should "just know", the same way it knows the target and the total prerequisites.

Note that the use of a pattern rule is a red herring: we can replace `%.o: %.c` by `foo.o: foo.c`.

Comment: This distinction is in your head only. Make has no such distinction.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your input. In my opinion, the distinction is codified in the syntax of the `Makefile`, because the right hand side of the pattern rule `%.o: %.c` is `%.c` and that matches only `foo.c`, and not `foo.h`. At some point, the program knows this. So, it is not only in my head.

Comment: You are assuming a *very* specific way of writing a makefile and only specific kinds of pattern rules. You are also not thinking about the way that make combines prerequisites. I'm not suggesting that make **cannot** know this distinction. I **am** suggesting that make does not *save* this information and does not consider this distinction the same way you do.

Comment: I agree that the idea of build-use versus freshness-use prerequisites is a potentially useful one (though the uses are probably limited to compilation cases like this) but that distinction just doesn't exist in make. The only prerequisite type distinction make has is for order-only prerequisites which do not do what you want here.

Comment: @EtanReisner Can you back that with citations to the GNU make source code? If it cannot be done, that would be useful to know. Do I have to write a patch for this? Say a new automatic variable like `$~` or whatever? I know about o-o prerequisites and have used them. A patch wouldn't be that useful because it would have to be upstreamed and it would create a dependency on bleeding edge GNU Make. Something that works in 3.81 would be nice. Nobody wants to ship an open source program that requires the latest gmake that must be obtained from the GNU ftp server and built from scratch. :)

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm open to a solution that parses the Makefile externally and produces the annotations which rules can access through some nice mechanism, like $(call WHATEVER,$@) (retrieve the primary prerequisites for this target from parsed Makefile data).

Comment: The problem with an external process is knowing which files match pattern rules. You would likely need to combine parsing the `make -d` output from a full build with the manual parsing of the makefile (or the `-p` output possibly since you would need to account for `eval` created targets ideally).

Comment: @EtaiReisner I just thought of a solution that is not general but will work in my case. All the secondary prerequisites in my case come from a dependency makefile. What I can do is change the representation of that file to a different form, since I control the generation. Instead of, say `foo.o: $(top_srcdir)/bar.h ...`, the file can contain `DEPS_foo := $(top_srcdir)/bar.h ...`. You see where that is going. These `DEPS` variables can easily be used to generate the rules, and `$(DEPS_$(STEM)) for a given stem gives us the secondary prerequisites.

Comment: That's going to require secondary expansion (I think) if you want to use `foo.o: $(DEPS_$*)` but if you don't do that then your define can use `$(DEPS_$*)` to filter out the secondary prereqs from `$^` yeah. I assume `$^` doesn't "just" do what you want in these cases?

Comment: To answer your "point me at the source" comment the answer is in `read.c` in the `eval` and `record_files` functions. The makefile is parsed line-by-line and target prerequisites are simply added as they are found. At least so it looks to me (I'd have to dig deeper to be sure I understood it all).

Comment: @EtanReisner I came up with a solution, of sorts: see answer. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to split your dependencies in this way?

Comment: @bobbogo For now, it's just for pretty printing. I want to have a make log which gives the information "target X was made from prerequisities Y, Z, using the C command", and want Y and Z to be the relevant prerequisites rather than indirect dependencies. Eventually, this information could be used to make a generic framework of commands. The direct prerequisites are required on the command line of a command. I could make a generic rule that handles cases like, say `foo.o: a.c b.c` without hard-coding into the rule the fact that there are two direct prerequisites, or using a suffix-based hack.

Comment: So (for now) you essentially want a list of pre-requisites that existed and were newer than the target, is that fair? (After all, if `config.h` was built by some perl script, subsequently causing `f.cpp` to be re-compiled, you'd want to know that (???).)

Comment: @bobbogo No, I don't care whether or not these "primary prerequisites" are newer than the target. The prerequisites which are newer than the target are a different, dynamic category, whereas this is static. For instance if `foo.o` has prerequisites `foo.c`, `foo.h` and `bar.h`, sometimes the only prerequisite which is newer is, say, `bar.h`. Yet, in this situation, a build command must be run which receives `foo.c` as an input, and produces `foo.o`. (`foo.h` and `bar.h` are inputs, but pulled in indirectly.)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to add an an intermediate dependency node, which captures the secondary prerequisites, and represents them as a single prerequisite. The phony prerequisite has a certain recognizable lexical form based on which it can be filtered out:

Proof of concept, closely based on `Makefile` in the question:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c.o

all: foo.o

secondary_foo.o: foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
    echo $^ > $@

foo.o: secondary_foo.o

define RULE_BODY
@printf "prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$^"
@printf "primary prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$(filter-out secondary_$@,$^)"
@printf "secondary prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$(shell cat secondary_$@)"
endef

%.o: %.c
    $(call RULE_BODY)
    touch $@
```

Output:

```
prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c secondary_foo.o
primary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c
secondary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
touch foo.o
```

Unfortunately, the build directory is littered with these intermediate files. Even if the propagation of the secondary prerequisites is handled in some other way, the `secondary_foo.o` file still cannot be a phony target; at the very least it must be an empty time stamp file.

---

The following alternative solution is more complicated, requiring computed variables, `eval`, and the use of a trick to store dependencies in variables, which are used to generate rules. However, it has the virtue that it doesn't generate a proliferation of timestamp files.

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c.o

OBJS := foo.o bar.o

all: $(OBJS)

# These variables give secondary dependencies for the objectg files,
# in place of rules. These would typeically be "farmed out" to
# a machine-generated dependency makefile which is included:
DEP_foo.o := foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
DEP_bar.o := bar.h xyzzy.h

define RULE_BODY
@printf "\n"
@printf "prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$^"
@printf "primary prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$(filter-out $(DEP_$@),$^)"
@printf "secondary prerequisites of %s are %s\n" $@ "$(DEP_$@)"
endef

%.o: %.c
        $(call RULE_BODY)

# Now the trickery: generate the dependency rules from OBJS and DEP_ vars:

# $(NL) provides newline, so we can insert newline into eval expansions
define NL


endef

# For each object <obj>, generate the rule <obj>: $(DEP_<obj>)
$(eval $(foreach obj,$(OBJS),$(obj): $(DEP_$(obj))$(NL)))
```

Output:

```
prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h
primary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c
secondary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h

prerequisites of bar.o are bar.c bar.h xyzzy.h
primary prerequisites of bar.o are bar.c
secondary prerequisites of bar.o are bar.h xyzzy.h
```

The disadvantage is that any additional dependencies must be inserted into the variables rather than asserted via an ordinary rule. For instance, suppose we want to recompile all the `$(OBJS)` if the `config.make` makefile is touched. We cannot just do this:

```
$(OBJS): config.make   # Oops, config.make is now considered primary
```

Instead, we stick to the `DEP_` variable scheme and do it like this:

```
$(eval $(foreach obj,$(OBJS),DEP_$(obj) += config.make$(NL)))
```

In other words, loop over `$(OBJS)`, and generate a `+=` variable assignment for each `DEP_` variable which adds `config.make`, followed by a newline, and `eval` the whole thing as if it were `Makefile` text.

When the above eval is inserted into to our `Makefile` (in front of the existing `eval`, not after) the output shows that `config.make` has been added to `foo.o` and `bar.o` as a secondary prerequisite:

```
prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h config.make
primary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.c
secondary prerequisites of foo.o are foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h config.make

prerequisites of bar.o are bar.c bar.h xyzzy.h config.make
primary prerequisites of bar.o are bar.c
secondary prerequisites of bar.o are bar.h xyzzy.h config.make
```

This is a workable solution which avoids temporary files, but is more challenging to understand for `Makefile` maintainers.

Also note that since GNU Make allows periods and slashes in variable names, something like the following is not a problem:

```
DEP_libs/parser/scan.o := config.h libs/parser/parser.h ...
```

In a rule, where `libs/parser/scan.o` is the `$@` target, `$(DEP_$@)` nicely gives us `config.h libs/parser/parser.h ...`.

Lastly, note that instead of the `eval` lines, the dependency generator could just generate the code and stick it into the dependency makefile. That is to say, generate the file along these lines:

```
DEP_foo.o := foo.h bar.h xyzzy.h config.make  # config.make tacked on
foo.o: $(DEP_foo.o)                           # also generated

DEP_bar.o := ... # and so forth
bar.o: $(DEP_bar.o)
```